# $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter

I define `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in **constant.php in application/config folder in codeigniter**. like:

```
define('DOCUMENT_ROOT',$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
```

but when i try to upload file **DOCUMENT_ROOT** path is not found. I define path like this in controller:

```
$output_dir = DOCUMENT_ROOT."/uploads/";
```

when i print **$output_dir** it's give output like this:

```
 D:\inetpub\webs\xyzcom/uploads/
```

code for file upload:

```
$output_dir = DOCUMENT_ROOT."/uploads/";
    $file = $_FILES['resume'];
    if($_FILES['resume']['name'] != "") {
        $allowedExts = array("pdf", "doc");
        $extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["resume"]["name"]));
        if (
            ($_FILES["resume"]["type"] == "application/pdf") ||
            ($_FILES["resume"]["type"] == "application/msword") ||
            ($_FILES["resume"]["type"] == "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document") &&
            ($_FILES["resume"]["size"] < 20000000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts)
        ) {

            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["resume"]["tmp_name"],$output_dir.$_FILES["resume"]["name"]);
            $value['resume'] = $_FILES["resume"]["name"];

            $this->xyz_model->update_tabel_user_data($user_id,$value);
            redirect(site_url(user/demo'));
          }
        }
```

Comment: i try your suggested answer but how file is uploaded without website path?

Comment: check echo "<pre>";  print_r($_SERVER);  in constant.php check what it prints for DOCUMENT_ROOT

Comment: i print <pre>"; print_r($_SERVER);  in constant.php  it gives output for [DOCUMENT_ROOT] => D:\inetpub\webs\xyzcom

Comment: try to use APPPATH

Comment: check echo APPPATH what it prints

Comment: Check if D:\inetpub\webs\xyzcom/uploads/ exists in your file system, and try to change "uploads" folder permissions to Everyone (just to see if it's a permission problem)

Comment: i print APPPATH and it's give output ->      application/

Comment: and where is uploads folder is located

Comment: @K.doe Codeigniter has it's own uploading library have you looked at that http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
DOCUMENT_ROOT
```

Try just

```
FCPATH . 'uploads/';
```